# How to adjust the position of infowindow in Google Maps V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to fit the infowindow in Google Maps v3 so that it will appear full?

Comment: You want the content area to expand/shrink based on the content? Any chance the InfoWindow could be taller then the map?

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946860/google-maps-api-infowindow-domready-event-invoked-twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InfoWindow have a minimum height, this is pretty much unavoidable. It will expand to contain any content taller then the mimimum. You can override the expand behavior by forcing your content to be a specific height.

Extra info: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#InfoWindowOptions

An option is to not use InfoWindow and roll your own "bubble" that is opened on click.

Comment: what I meant is the the height of infowindow exceeds the bounders of the map , so I want to fit the infowindow inside the Googla maps

Comment: Wrap the content in a container, probably a dv, with a max-height set.

Comment: Well then we must have a communication because I have scrollable InfoWindows implemented. When you say "that", what do you mean?